# postfix: what does /.+/ in pcre do?

Tags: regular-expression, postfix

I'm rewriting all sender addresses to one address in Ppostfix.

`main.cf` includes this line:

```
sender_canonical_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/canonical_sender
```

The file `canonical_sender` looks like this:

```
/.+/ name@domain.com
```

It works as it should and does everything I want, but I would like to understand what `/.+/` does and what the difference compared to `/.*/` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/.+/` is a regex that matches every string with **1** or more characters. `/.*/` is a regex that matches every string with **0** or more characters.

The . matches any character, and the * and + quantifiers qualify the preceding expression to be done 0-or-more times and 1-or-more times respectively.

In the context of postfix, both seem equivalent, since I don't think it can ever reach at that point with an empty recipient (the two regex only differ in their treatment of the empty string).

Comment: The author of the postfix guide i'm using wrote that `/.*/` leads into a loop when postfix has delivery problems and rewrites the empty bounce sender address

Comment: If it's indeed rewriting the empty bounce address then yes, that would be pretty bad :)